# PySpark filter using another dataframe having to and from date and group by using ids

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, filter

I have a dataframe `date_dataframe` in pyspark with Monthly frequency

`date_dataframe`

```
from_date, to_date
2021-01-01, 2022-01-01
2021-02-01, 2022-02-01
2021-03-01, 2022-03-01
```

Using the dataframe, I want to filter another dataframe having millions of records (daily frequency) by grouping them by id and aggregating to calculate average.

`data_df`

```
id,p_date,value
1, 2021-03-25, 10
1, 2021-03-26, 5
1, 2021-03-36, 7
2, 2021-03-25, 5
2, 2021-03-26, 7
2, 2021-03-36, 8
3, 2021-03-25, 20
3, 2021-03-26, 23
3, 2021-03-36, 17
.
.
.
10, 2022-03-25, 5
12, 2022-03-25, 6
```

1. I want to use `date_dataframe` to query (filter) `data_df`
2. Group by the filtered dataframe using ID
3. Finally aggregate to calculate the average value.

I have tried the below code to do this.

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

SeriesAppend=[]


for row in date_dataframe:

    df_new = data_df.filter((data_df.p_date >= row["from_date"]) & (data_df.p_date < row["to_date"])).groupBy("id").agg(min('p_date'), max('p_date'), F.avg('value') )    
    SeriesAppend.append(df_new)

df_series = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, SeriesAppend)
```

Is there more optimized way to do this in pyspark without using for loop?

Also, `date_dataframe` is nothing but start of the month date as start date and end date is start date + 1 year. I am okay with having different format for `date_dataframe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a sql function `sequence` to expand your ranges into actual date rows.  Then you can use a join to complete the work.  Here I changed the name of column `to_date` to `end_date` as `to_date` is a SQL function name and didn't want to deal with the hassle.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import min, explode, col, expr
df_sequence = date_dataframe.select( \
  explode( \
   expr("sequence ( to_date(from_date),to_date(end_date), interval 1 day)").alias('day') ) )
df_sequence.join( data_df, data_df.p_date == df_sequence.day, "left")\
.groupby( blah, blah blah...
```

This should parallelize the work instead of using a for loop.

Comment: Hi Matt, Appreciate your support.

Comment: I have used following code.
`df_sequence = date_dataframe.select( 'end_date',\
  explode( \
   expr("sequence ( to_date(from_date),to_date(end_date), interval 1 day)").alias('dates') ) )

df_sequence.join( data_df, data_df.p_date == df_sequence.day, "left")\
.groupby('end_date', 'id').agg(min('p_date'), max('p_date'), F.avg('value') )`